# remote debugging on Raspberry

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, gdb

I try to use Visual Studio to debug on Raspberry with "gdb", but it always shows "Loading symbols for module /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3" and never finishes loading so that I can not debug my program.

Does anyone knows how to solve it? thx!

Comment: Are there any error message if you wait till it's done? Maybe Speeding Up Raspberry Pi Debugging by Running GDB Locally could help: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/crossgdb/

Comment: no error message, the process of "Loading symbols for module /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3" will never be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "*sudo apt-get install gdbserver*" and change **Debugging Mode** to "*gdbserver*" in Visual Studio. 
You can find the Debugging Mode setting in **Right Click on Project > Properties > Debugging**

This works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to missing library in your pi. You can run this command for fix:

```
apt-get install libc6-dbg
```